# Delphi 6 - Create Excel chart from delphi application - data and chart on the same pagen

Tags: excel, delphi, charts, legend

I need to create a chart in excel in a delphi application based on some data from a table.

I created the excel worksheet and filled n rows of data from the table. Now I need to make the chart based on the data.

We have to add two Legent entries(categories) - D5:D15 and E5:E15
and one Horizontal(Category) Axis labels -F5:F15

I tried the following to get this.
When executed I got the error message

> Method 'setsourcedata' not supported by automation object.

I tried the `SeriesCollection.item.value` method then also the system gave the same message.

```
procedure TForm1.Make_a_Chart;
var
  Sheets,Ch1 : Variant;
begin
  ch1 := XLApp.ActiveWorkBook.Sheets[1].ChartObjects.Add ( 500,100,400,200 ); // creates a new chart in the specified 
  Sheets := XLApp.Sheets;
  ch1.Chart.ChartWizard (
                         Sheets.Item['Delphi Data'].Range['D5:D15'],   // 1  Source
                         xlBarStacked, //  2  The chart type.
                         8,            //  3  Format - The option number for the built-in autoformats. Can be a number from 1 through 10, depending on the gallery type.
                         2,            //  4  PlotBy - Specifies whether the data for each series is in rows or columns. Can be one of the following XlRowCol constants.
                         1,            //  5  CategoryLabels - An integer specifying the number of rows or columns within the source range that contain category labels.
                         1,            //  6  SeriesLabels - An integer specifying the number of rows or columns within the source range that contain series labels.
                         False,        //  7  HasLegend - 'true' to include a legend.
                         'My Report',  // 8  Title - The Chart control title text.
                         'Y Axis',      // 9  CategoryTitle - The category axis title text.
                         'X Axis',      // 10  ValueTitle - The value axis title text
                         2                //  11  ExtraTitle - The series axis title for 3-D charts or the second value axis title for 2-D charts.
                       );
  ch1.setsourcedata(Sheets.Item['Delphi Data'].Range['E5:E15'],xlColumns,2);
  ch1.Chart.ChartType := xlBarStacked;
// ch1.SeriesCollection.Item[1].Values := Sheets.Item['Delphi Data'].Range['E5:E15'];
end;
```

Comment: I read your post, didn't have an immediate answer and prepared to move on and then I saw it was from you, RRUZ.  Heck, I'll do anything to help a big contributor like you! :-) So, I looked again. First thought: welcome to the headache of OLE automation with Excel! Worthless error messages and non-existent documentation.  Any chance you could ship a master template that contains a VBA method that does some or all of this, and then invoke the method from Delphi?  It's a tacky work-around (with weaknesses due to macro security issues, etc.), but that's we do in these frequent situations.

Comment: I agree with Robert. I have some programs which use automation but when it came to drawing a graph, I used a native Excel macro to do the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling SetSourceData on a [ChartObject object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff846594.aspx), not a [Chart object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff846549.aspx). The ChartObject object is a container for the Chart object. The Chart object has the method [SetSourceData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841196.aspx), so use this:

```
ch1.Chart.SetSourceData(Sheets.Item['Delphi Data'].Range['E5:E15'],xlColumns,2);
```

**Edit:** Your codesample is very confusing. Please, when asking a question, try to tidy your code. I see a lot of unused variables and you use a variable `ch1` that isn't declared in the var section.

Comment: Yes. You are right.<br> Now I added the series values. <br>Could you pls say how do I specify the Axis(Category) values?